# Unlimited scrolling with JSON Adapter & ListView

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I'm using ListView that retrieves data from external URL with JSON.
When I run my app, it shows only maximum of 10 results since my api query returns maximum of 10 results PER page.

What i'm trying to do is, that when the user scrolls down to the end of this 10 results, it will load more results (one by one would be even greater) from my JSON external URL (API).

This is how I'm using my ListView & JSONAdapter:

**TabFragment1.java**

```
ListView mainListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        mJSONAdapter = new JSONAdapter(getActivity(), inflater);
        mainListView.setAdapter(mJSONAdapter);
getUpdates();
```

**getUpdates()**

```
private void queryUpdates(double lat, double lon, int distance) {

        // Create a client to perform networking
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        // Show ProgressBar to inform user that a task in the background is occurring
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Have the client get a JSONArray of data
        // and define how to respond
        client.get(API_URL + "?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&distance=" + distance,
                new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonObject) {

                        // 11. Dismiss the ProgressDialog
                        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        // update the data in your custom method.
                        mJSONAdapter.updateData(jsonObject.optJSONArray("docs"));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable throwable, JSONObject error) {

                        // 11. Dismiss the ProgressDialog
                        mProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.bad_connection);
                    }
                });
    }
```

**My JSONAdapter.java**

```
public class JSONAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    JSONArray mJsonArray;

    public JSONAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = inflater;
        mJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mJsonArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mJsonArray.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // your particular dataset uses String IDs
        // but you have to put something in this method
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        // check if the view already exists
        // if so, no need to inflate and findViewById again!
        if (convertView == null) {

            // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_place_update, null);

            // create a new "Holder" with subviews
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.myImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
            holder.myTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myText);

            // hang onto this holder for future recyclage
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            // skip all the expensive inflation/findViewById
            // and just get the holder you already made
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        // More code after this
        // Get the current book's data in JSON form
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) getItem(position);

        // Grab the title and author from the JSON
        if (jsonObject != null) {
            //Get from JSON
            String myImage = jsonObject.optString("myImage");
            String myText = jsonObject.optString("myText");

            //Replace Them
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(myImage).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(holder.myImageView);
            holder.myTextView.setText(myText);

            }

        return convertView;
    }


    // this is used so you only ever have to do
    // inflation and finding by ID once ever per View
    private static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView myImageView;
        public TextView myTextView;
    }

    public void updateData(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        // update the adapter's dataset
        mJsonArray = jsonArray;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    }
```

how I can show more results by adding &page=2, &page=3 to the API_URL and load these results in my ListVIew, in addition to the old results?